# getElementsByTagName searching down all levels of XML nodes

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have this XML file:

```
<root>
    <node1>
        <name>A</name>
        <node2>
            <name>B</name>
            <node3>
                <name>C</name>
                <number>001</number>
            </node3>
        </node2>
    </node1>
</root>
```

I am parsing the file, to get the name for each node, and the corresponding number if existing.

I use:

```
String number = eElement.getElementsByTagName("number").item(0).getTextContent();
```

This should give me something like:

```
Name | Number
A    | 
B    |
C    | 001
```

But I get:

```
Name | Number
A    | 001
B    | 001
C    | 001
```

So, I think the `getElementsByTagName("Number")` is looking for number node in all the children of a node. I don't want that. Does anybody know a workaround?

I thought of using XPath instead of the above method, but I really want to know if there's an existing way. Thanks

Comment: what you want exactly, please explain with your full code...

Comment: As I mentioned, I am just trying to get the name and number for each node. If there is no number, it should show like null. But, the method I am using searches down all descendants. I don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `javax.xml.xpath` APIs in the JDK/JRE to have much more control over the XML returned over `getElementsByTagName`.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File("filename.xml"));

        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
        Element element = (Element) xpath.evaluate("//node3/name", document, XPathConstants.NODE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to find parent node of say node3 (which should be node2) and then find it's name and number?

Comment: @user2611492 - You mean `Node.getParentNode()`?

Comment: I have used `getParentNode()`. I wasn't sure if that could be used with XPath too. Thanks for your suggestion, it worked.. I have one question though, is using XPath less efficient in terms of execution time? Coz my program is taking longer to execute now.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class XML {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File input = new File("D:\\sample.xml");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
    Elements allElements = doc.select("root");
    for(Element value : allElements){
        System.out.println(value.text());
    }
    String node3Num = doc.select("node3").tagName("number").text();

        System.out.println(node3Num);
}
```

}

Output:
A B C 001
C 001

I have used jsoup-1.7.2 jar (you can download from jsoup.org)

Comment: My whole project is setup using 'javax.xml.*' and 'org.w3c.dom.*'. But if nothing else works out, I will give this a try

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `eElement` variable is always one of the `<node1/>`, `<node2/>`, … elements in question, then the following code should work when you replace your own snippet mentioned above:

```
String number = null;
NodeList childNodes = eElement.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
  Node node = childNodes.item(i);
  if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
      && node.getNodeName().equals("number")) {
    number = node.getTextContent();
    break;
  }
}
```

The `number` variable will be `null` when there is no `<number/>` child; it will contain the number you need otherwise.